# Creating a Spacey Jazz Musical chord generator and assigning Different probabilities on each note using random

Tags: python

I am wanting to create a generator where I can give the generator notes and assign probabilities to each note separately when using random to generate a chord. In this example I have `["c", "e", "g", "b"]`, each note i want to have a different probability of being chosen, for instance, `C[4]` as in greatest possibility `E[2]` less probability `G[3]` and `B[1]`.
I also want to add a functionality that the entire four notes generate never repeat. So if `B` is rendered first which would be rare, then `C`, or `G` would be more likely to proceed — making this combination the rarest progression of the four notes `[B,E,G,C]`. This generator could be really pretty when the right understanding of music is added to it as well as generating some interesting progressions when second and third octaves are added to it. This example should be simple enough to achieve a route in this direction.

How do we assign different probabilities to each note and make it not repeat?

So far It plays a random of each note on each line

```html
import random

class Note:

    def __init__(self, name, note):
        self.name = name
        self.gender= random.choice(["c", "e", "g", "b"])



c = Note('c')
d = Note('d')
e = Note('e')
f = Note('f')

Your_Chord = Note(name)
print(Your_Chord)

print(c.gender)
print(d.gender)
print(e.gender)
print(f.gender)
```

I'm also getting an error how I want to print the title "Your Chord"

Answer (score 2):

your note class need to parameter to initialize name, note :

```
c = Note('c', 'yourNote')
d = Note('d', 'yourNote')
e = Note('e', 'yourNote')
f = Note('f', 'yourNote')
```

in the line Your_Chord = Note(name) name is not defined anywhere and also Note class need 2 parameters. So, you can define Your_Chord like:

```
Your_Chord = Note(c.name, c.gender)
or
Your_Chord = Note("AnyName", "AnyGender")
```

you can use numpy.random.choice to set probability distribution:

```
import random
import numpy as np
class Note:

    def __init__(self, name, note):
        self.name = name
        self.gender= np.random.choice(["c", "e", "g", "b"],1,[0.5, .2, 0.1, 0.2])[0]



c = Note('c', 'yourNote')
d = Note('d', 'yourNote')
e = Note('e', 'yourNote')
f = Note('f', 'yourNote')
Your_Chord = Note(c.name, c.gender)
print(Your_Chord)
print(c.gender)
print(d.gender)
print(e.gender)
print(f.gender)
```

output:

```
<__main__.Note object at 0x11593d978>
c
b
c
c
```

Comment: brillant!! but how do you give different probabilities to each note

Comment: I have edited the answer and added how you can set probability

Comment: That is beautiful!! But how do you make it not repeat the same note

Comment: I cant understand the question - how do you make it not repeat the same note. please explain

Comment: So like the sequence can’t have the same note on next line .. like in your example there is c three times

Comment: random.choice has no relation with one note to another. It works as the probablity given. Here probability of c is 0.5, e is .2 and so on. 
As the probability of c is much higher from the others it has the greater possibility to come more than other values

Comment: so how do I get it to print one line of notes and not repeat a note, should this be one string then rather than a print function for each note row

Comment: ["c", "e", "g", "b"] from this 4 elements you can chose unique elements not more than 4 times. I am not clear about the requirement.